# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/tools/javac/Main

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlets

Trying to run sample index.jsp page in eclipse Tomcat 4 Server.
JDK and JRE required for project are 1.5 but system JDK and JRE are 1.8

Getting the following error:

```
type Exception report

message Internal Server Error

description The server encountered an internal error (Internal Server Error) that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 
javax.servlet.ServletException: sun/tools/javac/Main
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:481)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:853)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:247)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)


root cause 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/tools/javac/Main
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.SunJavaCompiler.compile(SunJavaCompiler.java:136)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:272)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.loadJSP(JspServlet.java:548)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet$JspServletWrapper.loadIfNecessary(JspServlet.java:176)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet$JspServletWrapper.service(JspServlet.java:188)
```

Comment: The current version of Tomcat is 9.x. Why are you using Tomcat 4.x?

Comment: Wow, it looks like Tomcat 4.0.6 was released in October 2002. There's not even an end-of-life year given any more on the homepage (just that it is long beyond its lifespan). The last release in the 4.1 series seems to be from July 2003 (estimated end-of-life). You should definitely upgrade. The errormessage you see points at a JRE being available, but no JDK

Comment: I was using the default settings of eclipse webapp archtye and there this was the available server for the default jre and jdk 1.5. But I updated the project preferences to the latest jre and jdk and Tomcat 8 now its working . Thanks for pointing out my rookie mistake.

Comment: So the problem is solved now?

Comment: Yes it is, thanks a lot.